# how do I get just one value from mysql php query results

Tags: php, mysql

Below are the results of my query. I would just like to return the refundable_amount value. Which for this query $4.04

```
a:1:{i:0;a:19:{s:8:"label_id";i:3324543;s:8:"tracking";s:22:"9400136205309684548265";s:17:**"refundable_amount";d:4.04**;s:7:"created";i:1614781854687;s:10:"carrier_id";s:4:"usps";s:12:"service_name";s:23:"USPS - First Class Mail";s:6:"status";s:9:"PURCHASED";s:22:"commercial_invoice_url";N;s:12:"package_name";s:11:"Single Kcup";s:9:"is_letter";b:0;s:13:"product_names";a:1:{i:0;s:28:"Multiple Aware";}s:11:"product_ids";a:1:{i:0;i:1212;}s:15:"receipt_item_id";i:72845982;s:12:"created_date";i:1614781859000;s:11:"expiry_date";i:1630333858000;s:15:"main_receipt_id";i:54663164;s:4:"rate";d:4.04;s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:12:"label_cached";i:1614781863000;}}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: can you add the unserialized response ?

Comment: This is PHP serialised data. It should be possible to `unserialize()` it, but there's an error at `Multiple Aware`, which is shown as 28 bytes long, but is only 14. Change that and the data unserializes to an array of arrays from which you can pluck the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo, in near the "Multiple Aware" output, it should be 14, if you correct it like below,

Then you can use php unserialize function

```
$text = unserialize ('a:1:{i:0;a:19:{s:8:"label_id";i:3324543;s:8:"tracking";s:22:"9400136205309684548265";s:17:"refundable_amount";d:4.04;s:7:"created";i:1614781854687;s:10:"carrier_id";s:4:"usps";s:12:"service_name";s:23:"USPS - First Class Mail";s:6:"status";s:9:"PURCHASED";s:22:"commercial_invoice_url";N;s:12:"package_name";s:11:"Single Kcup";s:9:"is_letter";b:0;s:13:"product_names";a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Multiple Aware";}s:11:"product_ids";a:1:{i:0;i:1212;}s:15:"receipt_item_id";i:72845982;s:12:"created_date";i:1614781859000;s:11:"expiry_date";i:1630333858000;s:15:"main_receipt_id";i:54663164;s:4:"rate";d:4.04;s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:12:"label_cached";i:1614781863000;}}');
```

you can get the value as below,

```
echo $text[0]['rate'];
```

will output

4.04

For more information about this function you can visit
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Thank you @mahen3d that works very well.